# Advice on implementing "presence" for a web site?

Tags: node.js, nonblocking, ejabberd, user-presence

Ideally, I'd like to find simple, lightweight code that allows all the web clients connected to my site to maintain real-time status of who else is currently online.

I know ejabberd does this, but it also does a lot of other things, and I'd prefer a small code footprint so I can customize and understand its performance characteristics.

I like the non-blocking aspect of node.js, and was wondering if there's an open source project that does all this logic.

I'd also like to see a JavaScript implementation of maintaining this model on the client side.

Answer (score 5):

For real time status, use [socket.io](http://socket.io/). Every time someone connects add them to the connected users list. For accurate stats you will need to keep track of user sessions. See http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/

```
var onlineUsers = {};
var online = 0;

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  onlineUsers[socket.handshake.sessionID] = socket.handshake.session;
  online = Object.keys(onlineUsers).length;
  socket.broadcast.emit('online', online);

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    delete onlineUsers[socket.handshake.sessionID];
    online--;
    socket.broadcast.emit('online', online);
  });
});
```

Comment: Note this does not scale horizontally with multiple server processes. In this example the `onlineUsers` object is a property of the server's global object, and multiple servers will not share that data. Implementing real-time presence across a multi-node environment is much more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone reading this in the future. I started with the answer written by `fent`, but I needed some modifications since things have changed in the intervening 6 years since his answer was published.

I used a `Map` rather than an `Object` for storing the session information. this means that the `sessionID` is no longer required.

```
const onlineUsers = new Map();

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('connection initiated');

    socket.on('userInfo', userInfo => {
        console.log('userInfo', userInfo);

        onlineUsers.set(socket, userInfo);

        io.emit('onlineUsers', Array.from(onlineUsers.values()));
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log(onlineUsers.get(socket));

        onlineUsers.delete(socket);

        io.emit('onlineUsers', Array.from(onlineUsers.values()));
    });
});
```