# Node.js module for managing users who are online?

Tags: node.js

Are there any node.js module for managing users who are online?

By this I mean for a real-time application knowing who is available/connected. Sending messages between them, subscribing to events from different people, etc.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498005/user-authentication-libraries-for-node-js just set up socket.io to continue the connection

Comment: I would advising you add that to the Question, also just use mongodb + redis for the communications between servers

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661758/advice-on-implementing-presence-for-a-web-site/8662707#8662707

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like something you could easily do on top of socket.io.

Answer (score 0):

Integration of `socket.io` for real-time updates in `Node.js` is what you are searching for.

**Sample Code:**

```
io.on('connection',function(socket){  
    socket.on('update_list',function(data){
      //data.purpose;


      if((String(data.purpose.trim()))=='login'){
        var query="update user set online = ? where id = ?";
        con.query(String(query),['Y',data.id],function(err,rows){
         // var query="select * from user where id !='"+data.id+"'";
          var query="select * from user";
          con.query(String(query),function(err,rows){
            io.emit('logout update',JSON.stringify(rows));
          });
        });
      }else{
        var query="update user set online = ? where id = ?";
        con.query(String(query),['N',data.id],function(err,rows){
          //var query="select * from user where id !='"+data.id+"'";
          var query="select * from user";
          con.query(String(query),function(err,rows){
            io.emit('logout update',JSON.stringify(rows));
          });
        });
      }
    });
});
```

You can find the proper documentation here: [Online Users Node.js](http://www.codershood.info/2015/12/10/showing-online-users-using-nodejs-socket-io/)